# Decrypt Java AES GCM encrypted text in PHP

Tags: java, php, encryption, aes-gcm

Encryption and Decryption in same side works but can't decrypt Java AES GCM encrypted text using method below in PHP at all, always get false.

Java encryption:

```java
public static String encrypt(String stringToEncrypt, String encryptionKey) throws Exception
{
    byte[] encryptionKeyBytes = encryptionKey.getBytes();
    SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
    byte[] iv = new byte[12];
    secureRandom.nextBytes(iv);

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
    SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(encryptionKeyBytes, "AES");
    GCMParameterSpec parameterSpec = new GCMParameterSpec(128, iv);
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, parameterSpec);

    byte[] encryptedMessageBytes = cipher.doFinal(stringToEncrypt.getBytes());
    byte[] encryptedMessageAndIVBytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(iv.length + encryptedMessageBytes.length)
            .put(iv)
            .put(encryptedMessageBytes)
            .array();
    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encryptedMessageAndIVBytes);
}
```

PHP decryption:

```php
function decode(string $ciphertext, string $encryptionKey): false|string
{
    $ciphertext = base64_decode($ciphertext);

    $iv = substr($ciphertext, 0, 12);
    $tag = substr($ciphertext, -16);
    $ciphertext = substr($ciphertext, 12, -16);

    //Also doesn't work!
    //$tag = '';
    //$ciphertext = substr($ciphertext, 12);

    return openssl_decrypt($ciphertext, 'aes-128-gcm', $encryptionKey, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv, $tag);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

---

## Solved

by Topaco's comment:

> A possible explanation would be that you use a key that is not 16
> bytes large, e.g. 32 bytes. In the Java code the AES variant is
> determined by the key size (i.e. AES-256), on the PHP side by the
> specification (i.e. AES-128), and the key is silently truncated
> (resulting in different keys).

Comment: Without the IV you have no hope of decrypting the message.

Comment: Works fine for me, so it's probably your data. A possible explanation would be that you use a key that is not 16 bytes large, e.g. 32 bytes. In the Java code the AES variant is determined by the key size (i.e. AES-256), on the PHP side by the specification (i.e. AES-128), and the key is silently truncated (resulting in different keys). But this is just a guess. Post non-productive sample data, please.

Comment: Thanks @Topaco, fixed by using a 16 bytes key!